# Can you recommend tools and materials for building a gate like this?

Tags: wood

[image: wood gate]

I want to improve my home by building a nice gate like this one.  Can you recommend tools and building materials?

Mike

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Wood ID is even off-topic on Woodworking.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oak or teak has a much tighter grain pattern so yes, that's likely cedar, maybe redwood. Depending on where in the world you are, it might possibly be stained cypress (because cypress is generally lighter) or Goncalo Alves, a.k.a. "Tiger Wood", but that would be one heck of an expensive gate!